# Delete table from Visual Studio not reflected in SSMS

Tags: sql, database, ssms

I am using visual studio 2012 to build a database, then I publish it to the server.

when I add a table in visual studio and then publish, I can see this table using SSMS.

When I delete a table in visual studio and then publish, the table remains in SSMS.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To have the drop objects actually performed on the DB do the following:

1. right click on the project, and select publish.
2. Fill all the required fields, and click on advanced
3. Check the checkbox: "DROP Objects in target but not project"
4. Click on publish, and the objects will be dropped from the target.